# connmanctl having problem with complex passphrase

Tags: wifi, connection, osmc, password, wpa

The built in WiFi module seems to work fine, as it can connect to both of my open networks I created for testing, i.e. the 2.4GHz, and the 5.0GHz ones.

If I set a simple passphrase (i.e. contains only ASCII lowercase letters) to these networks it can still connect to them without any problem.

However if I set a complex passphrase (containing single and double quotes and other visible ASCII characters, like backslash, etc.) it cannot connect to those (although my other devices, such as an Arch Linux PC and an Android device can).

I'm using `connmanctl` to establish the connection and as far as I know it is using `wpa_supplicant` as the default agent under the hood.

The error message I got back is:

```
Agent ReportError wifi_x_y_managed_psk
  connect-failed
Agent request cancelled by ConnMan
Error /net/connman/service/wifi_x_y_managed_psk: Operation aborted
```

The following lines are probably also relevant from the output of the `journalctl`:

```
wpa_supplicant[418]: wlan0: Trying to associate with <MAC-ADDR> (SSID='test5g' freq=5100MHz)
wpa_supplicant[418]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:...:00 status_code=16
```

> My assumption is that `connman` is passing the passphrase to `wpa_supplicant` in a way that the double quote (`"`) is not escaped hence the password is trimmed and the authentication fails.  But this may not be the case, this is only my assumption.

Any ideas how to solve this?  Obviously the `My OSMC` > `Network` > `Wireless` GUI connection wizard is not working either, I guess it is using `connman` under the hood.

---

**Extra Info**

- **Board:** Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+
- **OS:** OSMC 2018.10-1 (latest as of writing this question)

---

**Update**

*Sigh* - It looks like it even has problems with too long passwords. (E.g. 32 is too long for it, but 16 is working fine). Why is the wireless handling so badly broken?

Comment: To be sure for testing: can you please give an example password that does not work on your system?

Comment: @Ingo something like: ``HElL\o{1"WOr`l'd/PasSwo&r0D26!``

Comment: Interesting question - I wonder, too, whether the password you are entering is what the system is seeing.  I initially thought that it might be worth comparing the `locale` that your user account is using compared to what `root` would, though further consideration suggests that would not be a factor after all {unless it was something like a setting for a French locale that was using `«...»` instead of `"..."`around strings}.

Comment: Perhaps report a bug? Debian [connman](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/connman). [Reporting bug in Debian](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting.en.html)

Comment: @PeterVaro Also, what version of connman do you have? I see some interesting password related fixes in 1.32 (current 1.36) [here](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/connman/blob/debian/sid/ChangeLog).

Comment: @SlySven the locale is the default one coming with OSMC, that is: `C` and `UTF-8`

Comment: @trishmapow I am thinking about it, if it turns out that this is indeed a bug, I will report it right away!

Comment: @trishmapow mine is `1.33-3+deb9u1` (the default that is coming with OSMC -- and supported by the `dist-update`)

Comment: Backslash is an escape character on terminal and various other places. Does it get any better if you type it as \\ in your configuration?